# Extracting a value from Sage verbosity output

Tags: sage, elliptic-curve

I'm a mathematician in need of some help with using Sage. I'm using the following code in order to find, using descent via 2 isogeny, an upper bound for the rank of different elliptic curves.

An example is:

```
 from sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.descent_two_isogeny import two_descent_by_two_isogeny
 E = EllipticCurve([0, 0, 0, 17, 0])
 S = two_descent_by_two_isogeny(E, verbosity =1)
```

Which outputs:

```
2-isogeny

Results:
2 <= #E(Q)/phi'(E'(Q)) <= 2
2 <= #E'(Q)/phi(E(Q)) <= 8
#Sel^(phi')(E'/Q) = 2
#Sel^(phi)(E/Q) = 8
1 <= #Sha(E'/Q)[phi'] <= 1
1 <= #Sha(E/Q)[phi] <= 4
1 <= #Sha(E/Q)[2], #Sha(E'/Q)[2] <= 4
0 <= rank of E(Q) = rank of E'(Q) <= 2
```

Now the piece of information I'm interested in is the very final number, the '2' which is given as the upper bound of the rank.

What I would like to do is find a way to extract this number from the output, so that I can run the code over many different elliptic curves and each time just receive a value for the upper bound of the rank, not the large text output.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
E.rank_bounds()
```

give you the answer you want? It outputs `(0, 2)`, and the documentation says, 'Return the lower and upper bounds using "simon_two_descent()".' (I'm a mathematician but this is not my area of specialty, so I don't know if `simon_two_descent` is giving the same rank information as `two_descent_by_two_isogeny`. I encourage you to type `E.<TAB>` and browse through the options to see if any are the right thing.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! To be honest, this is a new area for me too so I'm not 100% sure at the moment if it's the same - I'll check this out. It certainly does seem to agree on a lot of cases however! So either way this is really helpful for what I'm looking at in identifying potential cases that I can then check with my original code - thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 2):

For the quick answer, please skipt to the end of this message.

---

Details for the final short answer:

The code inside `two_descent_by_two_isogeny`, inspected in the ipython interprete for instance via...

```
sage: two_descent_by_two_isogeny??
```

shows that the "work" is -- after a preparsing (of the paramaters `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, `a6` of the given elliptic curve) -- delegated to `two_descent_by_two_isogeny_work`...

```
if a1==0 and a3==0:
    s2=a2; s4=a4; s6=a6
else:
    s2=a1*a1+4*a2; s4=8*(a1*a3+2*a4); s6=16*(a3*a3+4*a6)
f = ((x_ZZ + s2)*x_ZZ + s4)*x_ZZ + s6
x_list = f.roots() # over ZZ -- use FLINT directly?
x0 = x_list[0][0]
c = 3*x0+s2;  d = (c+s2)*x0+s4
return two_descent_by_two_isogeny_work(c, d,
    global_limit_small, global_limit_large, verbosity, selmer_only, proof)
```

and the returned value from this latter function can be also inspected...

```
sage: from sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.descent_two_isogeny import  \
....:      two_descent_by_two_isogeny
sage: two_descent_by_two_isogeny_work??
```

(Or just open the imported py-file, it's open source!)
The last lines, including the `return` line, are:

```
if verbosity > 0:
    print("\nResults:")
    print(n1, "<= #E(Q)/phi'(E'(Q)) <=", n2)
    print(n1_prime, "<= #E'(Q)/phi(E(Q)) <=", n2_prime)
    print("#Sel^(phi')(E'/Q) =", n2)
    print("#Sel^(phi)(E/Q) =", n2_prime)
    print("1 <= #Sha(E'/Q)[phi'] <=", n2/n1)
    print("1 <= #Sha(E/Q)[phi] <=", n2_prime/n1_prime)
    print("1 <= #Sha(E/Q)[2], #Sha(E'/Q)[2] <=", (n2_prime/n1_prime)*(n2/n1))
    a = Integer(n1*n1_prime).log(Integer(2))
    e = Integer(n2*n2_prime).log(Integer(2))
    print(a - 2, "<= rank of E(Q) = rank of E'(Q) <=", e - 2)

return n1, n2, n1_prime, n2_prime
```

Now going back to the sample code from the OP, let us also print the *4*-tuple `S`:

```
sage: from sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.descent_two_isogeny import \
....:      two_descent_by_two_isogeny
....: E = EllipticCurve([0, 0, 0, 17, 0])
....: S = two_descent_by_two_isogeny(E, verbosity =1)
....: S

2-isogeny

Results:
2 <= #E(Q)/phi'(E'(Q)) <= 2
2 <= #E'(Q)/phi(E(Q)) <= 8
#Sel^(phi')(E'/Q) = 2
#Sel^(phi)(E/Q) = 8
1 <= #Sha(E'/Q)[phi'] <= 1
1 <= #Sha(E/Q)[phi] <= 4
1 <= #Sha(E/Q)[2], #Sha(E'/Q)[2] <= 4
0 <= rank of E(Q) = rank of E'(Q) <= 2
(2, 2, 2, 8)
```

The returned tuple corresponds to the values `return n1, n2, n1_prime, n2_prime`, and the "final `2`" in the print is obtained from the the print command:

```
    e = Integer(n2*n2_prime).log(Integer(2))
    print(a - 2, "<= rank of E(Q) = rank of E'(Q) <=", e - 2)
```

So you want that `e - 2`.

---

Long story made short:

Use:

```
sage: from sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.descent_two_isogeny import \
....:      two_descent_by_two_isogeny
....: E = EllipticCurve([0, 0, 0, 17, 0])
....: S = two_descent_by_two_isogeny(E)
....: n1, n2, n1_prime, n2_prime = S
....: e = Integer(n2*n2_prime).log(Integer(2))
....: print(f"e = {e} so the needed upper bound for rank E'(Q) is e - 2 = {e-2}")
e = 4 so the needed upper bound for rank E'(Q) is e - 2 = 2
```

*Note:* Please also consider [John Palmieri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401572/john-palmieri)'s answer!